# How many ways to divide 5 different books among 3 children so that each child gets at least one book?

Tags: combinatorics

> How can you divide 5 different books among 3 children such that each child gets at least one book? (no book can be divided)

Some one please tell me how to solve this.

Comment: [Inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle)

Answer (score 2):

This is the number of onto functions from a $5$-element set to a $3$-element set.
Here, principle of inclusion & exclusion is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would use inclusion-exclusion. Count the total ways to distribute the books. Subtract three times the number of ways to give them to a specific pair. But you have subtracted the ways to gove them all to one child twice (paired once with each of the others) so add them in once.

Answer (score 0):

use the [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) method to see that there are 6 ways to give out 5 identical books.

Of these there are 3 combinations where you give 3 to one kid and 1 to the others and there are 3 combinations where you give 2 to one kid and 1 to the other.

in the ones where you give three to one kid divide by 3! to get the answer of 3*5!/3!=60 and in the one where you give 2 to 2 kids divide by 2(2!) to get 3*5!/2*2!= 90 so therefore there are 150 ways to do it.